# Linked Folders produces strange results

Tags: node.js, laravel, capistrano

I am trying to understand how the linked_dirs work. i have the following as an example

append :linked_dirs, "storage", "node_modules", "vendor", "public"

the above causes a few issues:

1: if i keep the "public" in the linked dirs, on initial deploy the public folder is missing a lot of files that are present in the git repository. For example, without the "public" listed in linked_dirs i get the following tree inside current/public:

```
[git@web003 current]$ ls -lh public/
total 52K
drwxrwxr-x  3 git git 4.0K Dec 12 16:48 custom
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git    0 Dec 12 16:48 favicon.ico
drwxrwxr-x  2 git git 4.0K Dec 12 16:48 fonts
drwxrwxr-x  4 git git 4.0K Dec 12 16:48 rsvp
drwxrwxr-x  2 git git 4.0K Dec 12 16:48 images
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git 2.7K Dec 12 16:48 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git 1.2K Dec 12 16:48 manifest.json
drwxrwxr-x  8 git git 4.0K Dec 12 16:48 maverick
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git   26 Dec 12 18:43 mix-manifest.json
drwxrwxr-x 15 git git 4.0K Dec 12 18:43 modules
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git   24 Dec 12 16:48 robots.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git  781 Dec 12 16:48 serviceWorker.js
drwxr-xr-x  4 git git 4.0K Dec 12 18:43 vendor
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git  914 Dec 12 16:48 web.config
```

With "public" set in linked_dirs i have the following directory tree in current/public

```
[git@web003 public]$ ls -lh
total 12K
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git   26 Dec 12 17:16 mix-manifest.json
drwxrwxr-x 15 git git 4.0K Dec 12 17:16 modules
drwxr-xr-x  4 git git 4.0K Dec 12 17:16 vendor
```

There is a lot missing and i am not entirely sure why. Also mix_manifest.js is a file that is generated and updated when we run some compile scripts, i'd like that to be shared but it seems i can't add it to linked_files since on initial deploy it does not exists and it returns an error:

00:02 deploy:check:linked_files
      ERROR linked file /var/www/xxx/shared/public/mix-manifest.json does not exist on xxx

2: This is similar to the above just with node_modules

If we share node_modules when trying to run npm run... it seems like it can't find certain files for example

```
npm run w-production // shortcut for:

cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--env.mixfile=build/w.mix" "--env.scss=1"
```

if the node_modules is not shared that works just fine. if it's shared it just compiles nothing, as it seems it can't really find the appropriate files since the node_modules points to a symbolic link.

Any idea what can be done in the scenarios above?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a directory in `linked_dirs` or a file in `linked_files`, you are instructing Capistrano that the **authoritative** versions/contents of those resources live in the `shared` directory. Implicitly that means the corresponding folders/files in git will not be used.

In the case of a linked directory, the shared version starts out completely empty. The assumption is that it is populated by the build process or by the app itself as it runs.

Two common examples illustrate this:

1. `public/system` is often linked as a location to put file uploads. When users upload images to the app, they are stored in a shared location and therefore accessible to future deploys.
2. `public/assets` and `tmp` are often linked to store the output and caches of `assets:precomplie`. This speeds up the precompile step in future deploys.

Importantly you would never check in `public/system`, `tmp`, or `public/assets` in to git. Capistrano has no mechanism to merge what is in git with what lives in `shared`. The `shared` location wins. In fact, every time you do a deploy, Capistrano *deletes* the specified files/directory (if they existed in git) before replacing them with symlinks.

To summarize:

- `linked_files` and `linked_dirs` tell Capistrano: "ignore whatever is in git for these files/directories; use the ones I provide in `shared` instead".
- If you specify something in `linked_files`, you must create it in `shared` before you deploy. Otherwise Capistrano has nothing to link to.
- For `linked_dirs`, if Capistrano can't find the specified directory to link to, it will create an empty directory as a convenience.
- During a deploy, Capistrano creates symlinks from the deployed code into `shared`. If any of `linked_files` and `linked_dirs` already exist in the deployed code, they are completely deleted before the symlinks are added.
- Linked files/folders should never be checked into git.

Comment: Thank You for this detailed explanation. Reading this through it now makes sense. I was linking the whole public folder rather than the sub folders that are ignored by git and are populated by the deployment process (public/build as an example). Thanks again.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as accepted to help other people that might have the same question? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that didn't realize i had to do that, i am not that familiar with stack overflow.